# INSERT INTO doesn't execute

Tags: php, database, pdo, insert, sql-insert

ı'm using a code block which ı already used in a different insert data process, but ı don't know why, it doesn't work. it sends me contact.php?in=error. what is the problem with my codes?

```
<?php 

if(@$_POST['submit']){

    $gizlicap = $_POST['hcaptcha'];
    $code = $_POST['captcha'];

    if($code == $gizlicap){
        $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ad'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['eposta'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
        $yazi = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');

        $snd = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `contactform` (`message_id`, `message_ad`, `message_email`, `message`) VALUES (NULL, :ad, :email, :yazi) ");
        $snd->bindValue(":ad", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $snd->bindValue(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $snd->bindValue(":yazi", $yazi, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($snd->execute()) {
            @header("Location: contact.php?in=success");
        } else {
            @header("Location: contact.php?in=error");
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Check security code!!';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you thought of logging the actual error message from the SQL?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` should be used to sanitize data being displayed on a web page, it's not for database data.

Comment: Side note: please get rid of those `@`s. Instead debug your code, use exceptions etc

Comment: ı delete @s but it is same and when ı delete htmlspecialchars() again it is same these are not solution...

Answer (score -1):

Do you have $db variable definied?
Use [try-catch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) instruction to handle exceptions, so you'll get message what is wrong.

Comment: It makes no sense to use try-catch instruction to handle exceptions, because exceptions report themselves

Comment: yes ı have $db variable and same code is working when ım trying to add blog essey into table... I seriously can't understand what is problem

Comment: ı forgot to make id column autoincrement, so thats why codes didn't work. Thank you all